# Anylogic: avoid unwanted execution of process in seize block

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling, statechart, event-simulation

I am trying to simulate manufacturing process by using statechart. And i have created agents for particular machines by statecharts and connecting those agents according to manufacturing process with help of resource pool, seize block and release block

[image]

My agent is passing through the resource pool and seize block. And I am expecting to run the model one after another seize blocks. However, when I run the model my all three statcharts are active at a same time, which I do not want. can anybody suggest me a possible way to avoid simultaneous process?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your manufacturing processes don't take 0 time. You're missing [Delay](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/delay.html) blocks, causing all your blocks to execute at the same, instantaneous moment.

On a side note, what you're showing us isn't a [statechart](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/statecharts/statecharts.html), but a flowchart.